# Return data if data exists in another table else return a default value

Tags: mysql, sql

Test data:

`TableA (ID_B, uniqueID, status)`

`TableB (ID_B, ID_C, info)`

Table A:

```
ID_B   uniqueID   status
124    12345678   registered
```

Table B

```
ID_B   ID_C   info
123    111    ilo
124    111    vey
125    111    ou
126    112    sup
```

I want to return `(ID_B, ID_C, info, status)` where status is a default status such as `'Default'` if there is no specified `uniqueID` available in `TableA`.

I have tried

```
SELECT * FROM tableB AS tB INNER JOIN(
SELECT ID_B, COALESCE(MAX(tA.status), 'default') as status
FROM tableA AS tA
WHERE  tA.uniqueID = '12345678'
) AS tC WHERE ID_C = 111
```

However, I'm receiving either all default statuses (when uniqueID does not exists in tableA) or all non-default status.

Below is an example of the output I want

```
ID_B  ID_C  info  status
123   111   ilo   default
124   111   vey   registered
125   111   ou    default
```

Comment: Please provide your original data, sl that it would be easy to have a solution

Comment: Do left join table A on B and in select use case when a.uniqueID is null then 'Default' else b.Status end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
`
SELECT b.ID_B, 
        b.ID_C, 
        b.info, 
        COALESCE(a.status, 'Default') AS status
 FROM tabelB AS b
 LEFT JOIN tabelA AS a ON a.ID_B = b.ID_B
 WHERE b.ID_C = 123;
```

`

Comment: Near perfect. All i had to do was add `...LEFT JOIN tabelA AS a ON a.ID_B = b.ID_B AND uniqueID=12345678`